# what is best practice for integration testing a database driven php?

Tags: php, database, integration-testing

Greetings;
   I am writing my integration tests so I would like to know what is the best practice for integration testing a database driven php site? Should I add and delete data in setup() and teardown() respectively for every test or should my test database just have the test data entered prior to any testing? 
 
   I am not asking about what tools to use but rather the approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my point of view the strategy to be used in tests, is a very personal decision of team. Usually in my projects I use BDD (Behavior driven development) to assurance the functionalities of API.

For example (Features of CRUD):

- I create a new data using the service (banana.create)
- I list all datas (banana.list) and check if the new data exists in then
- I list using filter (banana.list?id=xxx) and check if the structure of response is ok
- I delete the row (banana.delete) and check it using the service of list...

And for specifics components of model I use TDD (Test driven development) using the concepts of mock...

But, the main difficult are in design of application... not in tests :D

[]'s

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for the reply, I have a full set of unit tests for for my db class but they use mock db connections therefore needing implementation tests to verify the sql works. I could pre populate or add and delete it every time. Not knowing which is best is why I posted this question.

Comment: Jim, you should use database transactions (for example: begin in setUp and rollback in tearDown). But I prefer use a database with some template data and restore them.